# Hazelcast access using CLI

Tags: hazelcast

Suppose I have instance of Hazelcast running somewhere on remote machine and it executed in official Docker image. So I wolud like to see some data that Hazelcast stores just like in the first video [here](https://hazelcast.org/getting-started/). So I'm wondering is there any way to connect to existing Hazelcast instance from any CLI utility to get the data but **without Management Center**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Andrii,

You can take advantage of Hazelcast demo application.
You can find here:

- `com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp` member console, part of `hazelcast*.jar`. See [GH](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/console/ConsoleApp.java)
- `com.hazelcast.client.console.ClientConsoleApp` client console, part of `hazelcast-client*.jar`. See [GH](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast-client/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/client/console/ClientConsoleApp.java)

You can modify `server.sh` to run member / client in CLI mode

`java -server $JAVA_OPTS com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp`

or

`java -server $JAVA_OPTS com.hazelcast.client.console.ClientConsoleApp`

Let me know if you have any questions.
Thank you

Comment: Viktor, 

Thank you for the response. This is working for me. But there is inaccuracy in the javadoc that is provided in `com.hazelcast.client.console.ClientConsoleApp` for `main`. There specified that it expects `hazelcast.xml` file in the classpath but actually  it expects `hazelcast-client.xml` file.
Again thank you for your response.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Viktor Gamov I have found the way to see the data from CLI with provided `com.hazelcast.client.console.ClientConsoleApp` that is part of `hazelcast*.jar`.
Here is the small summary how to connect to existing instance using client:

1. Modify `clientConsole.sh` (that is located under `<hazelcast installation>/demo`) script (or create new one if you want) and the line in it have to be like that:
   `java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -cp .:../lib/hazelcast-all-<version>.jar com.hazelcast.client.console.ClientConsoleApp`
2. Put your config file to the same directory with your script (possibly `<hazelcast installation>/demo`)
3. Your config file should have the name exactly `hazelcast-client.xml` and may be look like the following:

```xml
<hazelcast-client xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config">
    <group>
        <name>dev</name>
        <password>dev-pass</password>
    </group>
    <network>
        <cluster-members>
            <address>localhost:5701</address>
        </cluster-members>
    </network>
</hazelcast-client>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to write a Java utility that can run from CLI. It can make use of `HazelcastClient` to connect to the cluster, get hold of IMap and print however you need. Also `IMap.getLocalMapStats` gives stats related to local map for that node.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to @Viktor Gamov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41287063/5821101) and @Andrii Pischanski's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41306500/5821101), I wrote a simple shell script to automate the process of:

1. Downloading the correct version of `hazelcast-all-<version>.jar` (containing the [`ClientConsoleApp`](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/client/console/ClientConsoleApp.java) class),
2. Creating the appropriate `hazelcast-client.xml` file for connecting to the cluster: https://github.com/YongJieYongJie/hazelcast-cli, and
3. Running the appropriate `java` command actually connect to the cluster.

Hope this proves helpful to someone.