# How to run Hazelcast command line console

Tags: console, client, hazelcast

Following this suggest: [Hazelcast access using CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225625/hazelcast-access-using-cli) I tried to run Hazelcast console in the following way:

1) Downloaded file hazelcast-client-X.Y.Z.jar

2) Run

```
/path/to/java -cp "/path/to/hazelcast-client-X.Y.Z.jar"  com.hazelcast.client.console.ClientConsoleApp
```

and I got

Error: Could not find or load main class com.hazelcast.client.console.ClientConsoleApp

Any suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`ClientConsoleApp` is not included in `hazelcast-client.jar`. Use `hazelcast-all.jar` instead. I just checked the latest version and `ClientConsoleApp` works fine.

```
$ java -cp hazelcast-all-3.12.jar  com.hazelcast.client.console.ClientConsoleApp
Apr 12, 2019 9:02:15 AM com.hazelcast.config.AbstractConfigLocator
INFO: Loading 'hazelcast-client-default.xml' from the classpath.
Apr 12, 2019 9:02:18 AM com.hazelcast.client.HazelcastClient
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple shell script to automate the process of:

1. Downloading the correct version of `hazelcast-all-<version>.jar` (containing the [`ClientConsoleApp`](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/client/console/ClientConsoleApp.java) class),
2. Creating the appropriate `hazelcast-client.xml` file for connecting to the cluster: https://github.com/YongJieYongJie/hazelcast-cli, and
3. Running the appropriate `java` command actually connect to the cluster.

Hope this proves helpful.

(Note: This is based on discussion over at this question: [Hazelcast access using CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41225625/hazelcast-access-using-cli/66261412#66261412.))